# Optimize Pagination and Filter Query Results with Count

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, pagination, filtering

I am having performance issues when dealing with pagination and filtering products as seen on many ecommerce sites, here is an example from Zappos

Kind of the standard: 
Showing 1-10 of 132 results. [prev] 1 2 [3] 4 ... 13 [next]
[10] Results per page

To me it seems like a large part of the problem is the query is run twice, once to count the number of results and again to actually populate the array. Below is the "filter" query:

```
SELECT product_id, product_title, orderable
FROM table_view
WHERE (family_title = 'Shirts' OR category_title = 'Shirts')
AND ((detail_value = 'Blue' AND detail_title = 'Color')
OR (detail_value = 'XL' AND detail_title = 'Size'))
GROUP BY product_id, product_title, orderable
HAVING COUNT(detail_title)=2
ORDER BY product_id
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The query takes about 20ms to run just by itself. The table it is selecting from is a view which is a join of about five different tables. The parameters that are passed in by the user are the "detail_value" & "detail_title" which are the filtering criterial. The "family" & "category" and then the Limit is set by the "results per page". So if they want to view all the results the limit is set to 2000. And every time they go to a new page via the pagination the whole query is run again. Below is a snippet of the PHP, $products is an array of the query results. And then the $number_of_results is a count of the same thing with the maximum limit.

```
$products = filter($value, $category_title, $number_per_page, $subcategory, $start_number);

$number_of_results = count(filter($value, $category_title, 2000, $subcategory, 0));

$pages = ceil($number_of_results / $number_per_page);
```

When run on my local machine the results page takes about 600-800ms to load, when deployed to Heroku the page takes 13-16 seconds to load. I've left out a lot of the PHP code, but I'm using PHP's PDO class to make the query results into an object to display in PHP. The tables being joined are the product table, category table, detail table, and the two tables linking them via foreign keys.

Google results show that this is a pretty common/complex problem, but I have yet to come across any real solution that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many queries for pagination generally need to run several times: once to determine how many records would be shown, then again to grab a screen of records. Then subsequent queries grabbing the next screen of records, etc.

Two solutions to slow pagination queries are:

1. Use a cursor to pull n-records from the open query resultset
2. Speed up the queries

Solution 1 can be expensive memory-wise for the server's resources and might not scale well if you have many concurrent users generating queries like this. It might also be difficult to implement cursors with the PDO class you're using.

Solution 2 could be done via improving view queries, adding indexes, etc. However that may not be enough. If the tables are read much more often than they are written to, you might try using UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE trigger tricks. Rather than running the query against a VIEW, create a table with the same column structure and data as the VIEW. Any time that one of the underlying tables changes, manually modify this new table to follow the changes. This will slow down writes, but greatly improve reading.